# How to detect and ban IP address making too much requests with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ip-address, apprequests

Does anyone know how to detect and ban the IP address or addresses automatically from which a lot of requests come in a very short period of time?

Example: someone has made a script to execute different special characters on an index page to try to slow or shut down the website:

```
https://website.com?name=23343jvugij
https://website.com?name=%ç*3233
https://website.com?name=SELECT_*"ç221
https://website.com?name=23+*+~33¬¬
https://website.com?name=&&%*ç"exit
https://website.com?name=count(*)#@|@
```

And the user keeps executing it, let's say 100 requests per minute. 
Is there a way to detect this and ban the users IP address immediately in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do it, but I suggest to go for https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter

It has an option to limit the rate based on remote IP address.

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, can you provide the code?

Comment: You can find out some tutorials, try by yourself. if you have any issues than the community will help you.